# Unable to generate Release SHA1 key in android Facing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android

In development mode my google signIn work fine but in Production mode I'm not able to SignIn from Google login So I found we have to create Release SHA1 key for Production but I'm Unable to Create It gives me error (noClassDefFoundError). Please help me where I'm Wrong.

[image]

Comment: keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}

Comment: #Edu Romero  Same Error

Answer (score 0):

Is the password for the .jks file you are trying to sign for correct?

Alternatively you could try generating a new .jks file like below:

In android studio. Build -> Generate Signed APK... and click Next and Generate New

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Ra7.png

Add your details here and Copy your key store path and key alias.

Traverse to the "bin" folder of the jdk path present in Java.

Open terminal and enter:

keytool -list -v -keystore "key store path" -alias "key alias"

Enter your key password and this will print out your release SHA1.

Check whether this works?